# TSQL Search Query between two dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to write a query that seems pretty straight forward.

The problem is in my `WHERE` clause. There are two fields in my table. A timestamp for when the task has started `startTime` and a timestamp for when the task was completed `endTime`/ Both of these fields are `Datetime`.

In my UI, I allow the person to select a `Start Date` and `End Date` and their filtering option.

The date logic should be as follows:

Everything where the `StartTime` is `>= @startDate` but `< @endDate` and the `EndTime` is `<=@endDate` but > @startDate.

I have done date ranges before using a single date in the database but not multiple so I am confused.

Any thoughts?

```
-- Fetch our data
    SELECT [recordID],
           [ItemID],
           [QID],
           [NTID],
           [EmpID],
           [FirstName],
           [LastName],
           [SupQID],
           [SupEmpID],
           [SupFirstName],
           [SupLastName],
           [Location],
           [Department],
           [Skillset],
           [BudgetMarket],
           CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), [startTime], 100) AS startTime,
           CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), [endTime], 100) AS endTime,
           COALESCE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, startTime, endTime), 0) AS totalTimeSeconds
    FROM   itemTracker_records
    WHERE  (@employee IS NULL OR (QID = @employee))
           AND (@supervisor IS NULL OR (supQID = @supervisor))
           AND CAST(endTime as Date) >= @startDate AND CAST(endTime as Date) < @endDate
    FOR    XML PATH ('results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: Sorry we couldn't help. Maybe next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be as simple as :

```
WHERE (StartTime  >= @startDate AND @startDate < @endDate )
 AND  (EndTime    <= @endDate   AND @endDate > @startDate)
```

Comment: `@startDate < @endDate AND @endDate > @startDate`? Redundant, no?

Answer (score 0):

Or, slightly shorter:

```
WHERE StartTime between @startDate AND @endDate 
  AND  EndTime  between @startDate AND @endDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "good" data, i.e. tasks always end after they start and the user supplied range is valid:

```
where startTime >= @StartDate and endTime <= @EndDate
```

As long as that is true then the task time span must be contained within the user specified range.

Note that a common problem is attempting to find date/time values between a pair of dates. To include all times on the last day it is necessary to add one day to `@EndDate` and remove equality from the comparison.